Get part of Register value from Ansible register output value
Trying to get specific property values from ansible register output. attaching output value below. please help here to get the value. it's quite complex nested for me to get as am completely new to ansible.
enter image description here

Register output,
"msg": {
“Changed”: false,
“msg”: “All items completed”,
“results”: [
{
"ansible loop var": "item",
"changed": false,
"exists": true,
"failed": false,
"item": [
"TMS",
"InterThread"
],
"properties": {
"Audit": {
"raw value": 1,
"type"; "REG _DWORD",
"value": 1
},
"Authenticator": {
"raw_value": "111",
"type": "REG_SZ",
"value": "111"
},
}
}
]
}
Wanted to get properties values from above register value,
Debug

Msg: {{Audit : 1 : REG_DWORD}}
Msg: {{Authenticator: 111: REG_SZ}}


https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-nested-variables

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

A minimal reproducible example
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    results: [
      {
        "ansible loop var": "item",
        "changed": false,
        "exists": true,
        "failed": false,
        "item": [
          "TMS",
          "InterThread"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "Audit": {
            "raw value": 1,
            "type": "REG_DWORD",
            "value": 1
          },
          "Authenticator": {
            "raw_value": "111",
            "type": "REG_SZ",
            "value": "111"
          },
        }
      }
    ]

  tasks:

  - name: Audit
    debug:
      msg: 'value: "{{ (results | first).properties.Audit.value }}" has type: "{{ (results | first).properties.Audit.type }}"'

  - name: Auth
    debug:
      msg: 'value: "{{ (results | first).properties.Authenticator.value }}" has type: "{{ (results | first).properties.Authenticator.type }}"'

will result into an output of
TASK [Audit] ****************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 'value: "1" has type: "REG_DWORD"'

TASK [Auth] *****************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 'value: "111" has type: "REG_SZ"'


thanks much, properties have many values and wanted loop and get all. any idea ?

@soundar, sure, but you'll probably need to read How do I ask a good question?, How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example before and update your initial question by editing it.
